# which is the full-expression when the rule says the full-expression of initialization

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer

```cpp
struct S {
  constexpr S(int i): I(i),D(i) { }       // full-expressions are initialization of I and initialization of D 
private:
  int I;
  int D;
};
int main(){
  constexpr S s1 = 1;  //full-expression comprises call of S​::​S(int)
}
```

According to the definition of full-expression:

> A full-expression is
>
> > 1. an unevaluated operand,
> > 2. a constant-expression,
> > 3. an init-declarator or a mem-initializer, including the constituent expressions of the initializer,
> > 4. an invocation of a destructor generated at the end of the lifetime of an object other than a temporary object, or
> > 5. an expression that is not a subexpression of another expression and that is not otherwise part of a full-expression.

> For an initializer, performing the initialization of the entity (including evaluating default member initializers of an aggregate) is also considered part of the full-expression.

The bullet 3 says `s1 = 1` is a full-expression because it's an init-declarator and `I(i)` is a full-expression due to it's a `mem-initializer` and similarly for `D(i)`.  It means that initialize entity `s1` can contain more than one full-expression?  In this case, Which is the full-expression of the initialization in this set of full-expressions?

Comment: Why do you think `1` is a *constant-expression*?  Why would the constructor call not be part of the *init-declarator*?

Comment: @DavisHerring Yes, you are right `1` is not a  constant-expression but a constant expression. So what's the full-expression of the initialization here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course full-expressions can be **dynamically** nested: consider

```
void f(int i) {
  ++i;   // (useless) full-expression
}
void g() {
  f(1);  // full-expression
}
```

As such, there’s no conflict between initializing `s1` being part of the *init-declarator* full-expression while also containing full-expressions for its *mem-initializer*s.

Comment: So, what is the full-expression of the initialization in my question? Or it means all full-expressions?

Comment: @jackX: Why would it be anything other than the relevant *init-declarator*’s full-expression?  That’s, well, the initialization.

Comment: You mean any full-expression other than init-declarator’s full-expression?

Comment: @jackX: Isn’t that exactly what I said?

Comment: So why the sentence says `the full-expression of the initialization shall be a constant expression.` It sounds like the full-expression of the initialization only has one.

Comment: @jackX: It *has* only one, which (dynamically) *contains* others.

Comment: Oh, the init-declarator’s full-expression is such full-expression which (dynamically) contains others.